# Непонятно работает if в программе, хотя использую equals

Tags: java

Почему при подаче на вход в программу строки из одинаковых символов, if прибавляет к счетчику единицу, хотя они равны? Например строка "ZZZ" = [ZZ,ZZ,ZZ], первый равен второму и т.д., но счетчик увеличивается

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    int cnt=1;
    String str = scanner.next();
    int n = str.length();
    ArrayList<StringBuffer> res = new ArrayList<StringBuffer>();
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(str);
        sb.deleteCharAt(i);
        res.add(sb);
        sb=new StringBuffer(str);
    }
    System.out.println(res);
    for (int i=0; i<res.size()-1; i++) {

        if (!(res.get(i).equals(res.get(i+1)))) {
            cnt++;
        }


    }
    System.out.println(cnt);

}
```

Comment: Подсказка: если сравнение работает как-то не так, то выведите на печать то, что сравниваете. Сразу станет видно, то ли сравнивается, что нужно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

res.get(i) - возвращает StringBuilder. Затем Вы вызываете equals для него. Фишка в том, что StringBuilder никак не переопределяет equals(), а напрямую его наследует от Object. Так что в Вашем случае equals проверяет НЕ эквивалентность строк, а то, что StringBuilder-объекты - совпадают. А поскольку они- разные экземпляры, то equals возвращает false, и соответсвенно срабатывает if. Условие необходимо переписать примерно в следующее:

```
if (!(res.get(i).toString().equals(res.get(i+1).toString()))) {
   cnt++;
}
```

Да и вообще, использование StringBuilder-обертки имеет непонятный смысл. Почему не использовать просто строки...